# How to declare an interface inside an component on Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

i've been trying to figure out how can i create an interface on ionic and then declare an observable that stores an array of objects inside my variable. Im having problems to figure out how to pass an interface inside my components and declare 2 global variables

i am trying to pass the following interface into my app.component.ts

```
    interface Usuario{
  nome: string,
  sexo: string,
  cpf: string,
  nascimento: string,
  email:string,
  telefone: string,
  endereço:string,
  login:string,
  senha:string

}
```

However, once i do so, i get an error over @Component({}) saying Decorators are not valid here and inside export class MyApp{} im trying declare my global variables that will return my observable storing an array of usuario.

Here's the full code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})

interface Usuario{
  nome: string,
  sexo: string,
  cpf: string,
  nascimento: string,
  email:string,
  telefone: string,
  endereço:string,
  login:string,
  senha:string

}



export class MyApp {


  rootPage:any = HomePage;

  usuario: Observable<Usuario[]>;
  usuarioCollectionRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<Usuario>;
  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot declare like that, you need to use export and then Interface definition. However i would recommend you to have a separate model file as follows,

```
export interface Usuario{
  nome: string,
  sexo: string,
  cpf: string,
  nascimento: string,
  email:string,
  telefone: string,
  endereço:string,
  login:string,
  senha:string

}
```

and import in your component.ts as ,

```
import { Usuario } from '../models/Usuario';
```

Comment: It does work, however i get the following error now: File 'C:/Users/Ionic Firestore 2.0/firestore-crud/src/app/providers/usuario.interface.ts' is not a module.

Comment: check the path is correct. The path starts in the main src as it is a parallel of www. Also if the folder for models is  in the same as index.html just use. /models/usuario.

Answer (score 0):

I had that error happen to me once. 
Put the interface before the @Component. The decorator is for the class and if you put the interface it getting an error because the Decorator can't "decorate"  an interface.